# Qt QDtls error while handling a handshake

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, network-programming

I am trying to create simple server-client program just to send data between computers in local network. For that purpose I use Qt Network and QDtls in particular. I wanted to make a small test just to make sure everything works how I expect it to work. Well, it doesn't.
So here is what I have on server part:

```
int main() {
    QUdpSocket serverSocket;
    serverSocket.bind(QHostAddress("192.168.1.73"), 22334);
    serverSocket.waitForReadyRead(-1);
    QByteArray clientHello(serverSocket.pendingDatagramSize(), Qt::Uninitialized);
    QHostAddress address;
    quint16 port = {};
    serverSocket.readDatagram(clientHello.data(), clientHello.size(), &address, &port);
    QDtls serverDtls(QSslSocket::SslServerMode);
    auto config = QSslConfiguration::defaultDtlsConfiguration();
    config.setDtlsCookieVerificationEnabled(false);
    serverDtls.setDtlsConfiguration(config);
    serverDtls.setPeer(address, port);


    bool v = serverDtls.doHandshake(&serverSocket, clientHello);
    std::cout << v << " ";
    serverSocket.waitForReadyRead(-1);
    serverSocket.readDatagram(clientHello.data(), clientHello.size(), &address, &port);
    v = serverDtls.doHandshake(&serverSocket, clientHello);
    std::cout << serverDtls.dtlsErrorString().toStdString();
    std::cout << " " << v;
```

And here is client code:

```
int main() {

QDtls a(QSslSocket::SslClientMode);
    QUdpSocket b;
    a.setPeer(QHostAddress("192.168.1.73"), 22334);
    auto config = QSslConfiguration::defaultDtlsConfiguration();
    config.setDtlsCookieVerificationEnabled(false);
    a.setDtlsConfiguration(config);
    b.connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.1.73"), 22334);
    
    bool v = a.doHandshake(&b);
    std::cout << v;
    
    b.waitForReadyRead(-1);
    quint16 port;
    QHostAddress address;
    QByteArray server_hello(b.pendingDatagramSize(), Qt::Uninitialized);
    b.readDatagram(server_hello.data(), server_hello.size(), &address, &port);
    std::cout << b.errorString().toStdString();
    bool k = a.doHandshake(&b, server_hello);
    std::cout << k;
}
```

Here is what I do:

1. Run server
2. Wait like 2 seconds
3. Run client

So nothing special. But here is the output:

Server: 1 Error during SSL handshake: error:14102410:SSL routines:dtls1_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure 0

Client: 1Unknown error0

So as you can see, the first handshake actually happens. The problem is with the second one and it appears that problem is with server code.

If it's important, I am using Ubuntu 20, Qt 5.13, mentioned IP is correct and port is also free.

Comment: And also maybe it's important to mention that I am trying to run this on one computer

Answer (score 0):

Like one great man said: "I figured it out". So this code has a bunch of problems:

1. When using QDtls, you have to pay attention to signal called pskRequired() - it is called during the second handshake attempt and you should connect some slots to it.
2. It was better to put code in a loop and check if handshake is done - it was strage to think that two iterations are enough